# word extraction and splitting using Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `"'GLO', FLO"` Now, I want a `regex` expression that will check each words in the string and if:
-word begins and ends with a single quote, replace single quotes with spaces
-if a comma is encounted between words split both words using space.

so, in the end, I should get `GLO FLO`.

Any help on how to do this using `replaceAll()` method on the string?

This regex didn't do it for me : `"'([^' ]+)|\\s+'"`

```
public static void displaySplitString(final String str) {
   String pattern1 = "^'?(\\w+)'?,\\s+(\\w+)$";
   StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(str, " , ");
   while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
     String delim = (strTok.nextToken());
     delim.replaceAll(pattern1, "$1$2");
     System.out.println(delim);
   }
 } //in main method displaySplitString("'GLO', FLO");
```

Comment: `split` is not same as replacement

Comment: @shA.t sorry, it didn't do it.

Comment: What about [this example code](http://ideone.com/tnZ3Ka)? Does it work for you?

Comment: So try this `/.*?([^',]*\w)/g` with `\1` ;).

Comment: @stribizhev I got this :
'GLO'
FLO
with your code. I should get this :
GLO
FLO

Comment: Please post your code. As you see, I get `GLO GLO`.

Comment: @shA.t is the with '\1' part of a regex expression?

Comment: @stribizhev, here is my code :

public static void displaySplitString(final String str) {
  String pattern1 = "^'?(\\w+)'?,\\s+(\\w+)$";
  StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(str, " , ");
  while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {

   String delim = (strTok.nextToken());
   delim.replaceAll(pattern1, "$1$2");
   System.out.println(delim);
   }
  
  }
  
  //in main method
  displaySplitString("'GLO', FLO");

Comment: Yes with using substitution of `\1` ;).

Comment: @helpdesk: How about [this one](http://ideone.com/vaJ9rj)? Note I removed `final` from the `str` declaration, or we'll need to introduce another variable.

Comment: @stribizhev : the second version works now but please, could you explain why the first one didn't work and also I don't understand this regex you have used : ^'?(\\w+)'?(?=\\S). what is the ?() and (?= \\s) doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [the snippet](http://ideone.com/vaJ9rj) that should get you going:

```
public static void displaySplitString(String str)
    {
        String pattern1 = "^'?(\\w+)'?(?=\\S)";
        str = str.replaceAll(pattern1, " $1 ");
        StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(str, " , "); 
        while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            String delim = (strTok.nextToken()); 
            System.out.println(delim); 
        }
    }
```

Here,

- I change `str` argument declaration as not `final` (so that we could change the `str` value inside the method)
- I am using the first regex `^'?(\\w+)'?(?=\\S)` to remove potential single quotes from around the first word
- Since you use a `StringTokenizer`, just 2 lines inside the `while` block are enough.

The regex means:

- `^` - Start looking for the match at the very start of the string
- `'?` - match 0 or 1 single quote
- `(\\w+)` - match and capture 1 or more alphanumeric symbols (we'll refer to them as `$1` in the replacement pattern)
- `'?` - match 0 or 1 single quote
- `(?=\\S)` - match only if there is no space after the optional single quote. Perhaps, you can even replace this lookahead with a mere `,` if you always have it there, after the first word.

Comment: the last statement is unclear. What 'optional hyphen' are you talking about in the (?=\\S) statement?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the quote.

Comment: out of curiosity, I studied abit of lookahead today and it seems your last statement is confusing and misleading though. The regex (?=\\S) checks that the next character after the optiona '? is a space. So, the statement "..if there is no space.." is misleading. Does that make sense?

Comment: `\S`  matches a non-space character. `(?=\S)` means check if next chacharacter is a non whitespace, but do not consume it. So the match won't have  this nonwhitespace character.It is like a boundary  here.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. The 'capital' S. I also noticed the regex : "^'?(\\w+)'?(?=\\S)" will not handle this string : "'GLO', 'FLO', 'BLO'". It will only take out the single quotes from GLO but not from the other two. Any modification to the regex so that single quotes are removed from any string containing words surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: Try this  one: `'?(\\w+)'?(?=(\\S|$))`

Comment: didn't do it. What is the | doing in the regex by the way?

Comment: Have a look. [it works for me](http://ideone.com/po6GAD). The pipe symbol stands for OR in regex.

Comment: So, it (?=(\\S|$) means "check if next chacharacter is a non whitespace OR end of line" because the $ sign means the end of the line in regex. Is that a way for the string to keep checking that it is end of line and if not, it just repeats the other expression: '?(\\w+)'?

Comment: `(?=(\\S|$)` is used as a boundary for `\w+`. Since the single quotes are optional, the regex engine should know where to stop. I assume there are commas that will stop `\w+` patterns, but I do not know the input so well as you, thus, I am assuming there must be either a non-whitespace letter or end of **string** (there is no multiline option here, so `$` matches end of string) right after a word character and an optional quote. Word boundary cannot be used. Perhaps, you do not need it at all. Try with just `'?\\w+'?` if you always have just comma-delimited words.